# Save pandas dataframe head(5), statistics, and plot as a picture output

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to save them as a png or other image output?
The output image need to include:

```
df.head(5)
df[column].describe()
distribution plot
or histogram plot
```

(or any other plots...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want to achieve:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(20, 10))

# hide axes
# fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax[0][0].axis('off')
ax[0][1].axis('off')
ax[0][1].axis('tight')
ax[0][0].axis('tight')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

ax[0][0].table(cellText=df.head().values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')
ax[0][1].table(cellText=df.describe().values, colLabels=df.describe().columns, rowLabels=df.describe().index, loc='center')

df.plot(kind='hist', ax=ax[1][0])
df.plot(kind='box', ax=ax[1][1])

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer for others to see :)

Comment: great answer, I was interested in it!

Comment: @JulienRoullé Thank you Julien, I can finally upvote people now ...lol